# what is the probability (related bayes theorem)

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Question is

There are 8 fair coins (C0)and 3 unfair coins(C1) (80% chance get head)
tosses it n times without looking at it , and reports:

n=2, got 1 T and 1 H , don't know the order. what is the probability the coin is fair coin?

My solution:

Have two situations , either to be HT or TH
so calculate Pr[ C0 | HT] = (Pr[HT | C0] * Pr[C0])/Pr[HT]=0.807 using bayes theorem.

Similarly , Pr[ C0 | TH] = ( Pr [ TH | C0] * Pr[C0])/Pr[TH]=0.807

So the question is do I add up these situation or get product from them to calculate the probability ? I feel like because probability values were expressed in the range 0 ≤ P≤ 1,

but I am not so sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not add the probabilities together.  You should be able to see this as it would lead to a number greater than $1$, which cannot be a probability, as you have said.

Your calculation should be $$\Pr[ C_0 | HT \text{ or } TH] = \dfrac{\Pr[HT \text{ or } TH | C_0]  \;\Pr[C_0]}{\Pr[HT \text{ or } TH]}$$

and you will find it gives the same value of about $0.807$, since $\Pr[HT \text{ or } TH | C_0]=2\Pr[HT  | C_0]$ and $\Pr[HT \text{ or } TH]=2\Pr[HT ]$.

Comment: Actually the value is about $0.8064516$, which would round to $0.806$

Comment: you are right , thank you !